# Why there is no logged in user after "ssh root@server 'last | head'"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

How does Linux act when I run this?

```
ssh root@server 'last | head'
```

I see the following output when I run multiple this command:

```
root     pts/0        MyIPv4            Fri Dec 30 16:17 - 16:17  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-56-generi  Fri Dec 30 01:03   still running
get      pts/1        MyIPv4            Thu Dec 29 10:05 - 10:11  (00:05)
get      pts/1        MyIPv4            Thu Dec 29 08:31 - 09:20  (00:48)
root     pts/1        MyIPv4            Wed Dec 28 13:12 - 13:34  (00:21)
root     pts/1        MyIPv4            Tue Dec 27 21:56 - 21:56  (00:00)
root     pts/3        tmux(3176049).%1  Tue Dec 27 09:27 - 09:28  (00:01)
root     pts/2        tmux(3176049).%0  Tue Dec 27 09:26 - 09:28  (00:02)
root     pts/1        MyIPv4            Tue Dec 27 09:26 - 09:28  (00:02)
root     pts/1        MyIPv4            Mon Dec 26 20:33 - 20:35  (00:01)
```

Is there any way to see if there's been login with command like above?

I also checked this but got no results:

```
ssh root@server 'history'
```

```
ssh root@server 'history | tail'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the wtmp log used by `last` is used to record *interactive* logins, i.e. ones that have a terminal (tty) associated with them. (Similarly, the utmp file used by `who` only lists currently active terminal sessions, not other login types.)

An `ssh host` or `ssh -t host cmd` will allocate a terminal and will show up in `who` (utmp) or `last` (wtmp), but `ssh host cmd` or `ssh -T host` will not.

In other words, wtmp is not an authentication log or a security audit log. Use the PAM logs found in /var/log/auth.log (or similar) if you want an accurate record of all authentications.

On servers which use systemd, `loginctl` may have a more accurate list of sessions.

Answer (score 1):

> If a command is specified, it will be executed on the remote host
> instead of a login shell.

- SSH man page

I.e. the command is run without the user being logged in. This is the reason why your approach does not work.

However, SSH logs all connections (and connection attempts) by default. Just run `journalctl -u ssh.service` on the server to check when smb. (tried to) connect to the server.